# Getting results from database into textarea

Tags: html

I have an edit page that fills the content with the original content from the database, I am using inline php  this populates the field with the title, and all the other fields work as well. When i try and fill the textarea using the same method it doesn't work.
All the other fields are varchar except the textarea which is text.
The php is in the value of the form.

```
            require_once('includes/db.inc.php');
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT
                            postID,title,content,author,image 
                            FROM posts where postID = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("i",$_GET['postID']);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($postID,$title,$content,$author,$image);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();


            ?>
            <section id="createPost">
                <form method="post" action="editPost.php">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Edit Post: <?php echo $title ?></legend>
                        <input name="postID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $postID; ?>">
                        <label for="titleOfPost">Title of Post:</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="titleOfPost" size="82" placeholder="Enter title of post" required value="<?php echo $title ?>"><br />
                        <label for="bodyOfPost">Content of Post:</label><br />
                        <textarea cols="60" name="postContent" rows="10" placeholder="HTML tags allowed" value="<?php echo $content ?>"></textarea><br />
                        <label for="authorOfPost">Author:</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="authorOfPost" size="82" placeholder="Author name" required value="<?php echo $author ?>"><br />
                        <label for="imageOfPost">Image:</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="imageOfPost" size="82" placeholder="image" value="<?php echo $image ?>"><br />


                        <input type="submit" name="newPostBtn" value="EditPost" id="newPostBtn"/>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </section><!--end createPost-->
```

Comment: Whenever something isn't working, always, always, always, always, always start by looking at the generated HTML source code. If you had done that, you'd have seen the data was actually being sent to the browser and known that this is not a PHP/MySQLi issue, but a simple HTML issue caused by a misunderstanding of the `textarea` tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Textarea element doesn't a have property *value*. Use:

```
<textarea cols="60" name="postContent" rows="10" placeholder="HTML tags allowed"><?php echo $content ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 5):

Textareas aren't populated like other input types.  The content goes between the tags (like an anchor tag) not within the opening tag (like an image tag).

Comment: Do I still need the php in the value of the textarea? or does it not matter

Comment: There is no value property for a textarea, so no.  You just use `<textarea><?php echo $somevariable; ?></textarea>`

Comment: @StudentRik [Read the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.7). `textarea` has no `value` attribute.